# ColdFusion9 orm properties in script

Tags: orm, coldfusion

I'd like to write the following in script syntax rather than the old style tag syntax.

```
<cfcomponent persistent="true" table="AuditType" schema="Audit" >
    <cfproperty name="AuditTypeID" column="AuditTypeID" ormtype="int" fieldtype="id" />
    <cfproperty name="AuditTypeName" column="AuditTypeName" ormtype="string"  />
    <cfproperty name="AuditTypeSort" column="AuditTypeSort" ormtype="integer" />
</cfcomponent>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the cfscript syntax really is quite similar,

```
component persistent="true" table="AuditType" schema="Audit" {
  property name="AuditTypeID" column="AuditTypeID" ormtype="int" fieldtype="id";
  property name="AuditTypeName" column="AuditTypeName" ormtype="string";
  property name="AuditTypeSort" column="AuditTypeSort" ormtype="integer";
}
```